# Arithmetic mean of nested vectors

Tags: clojure

My plans is to compute the arithmetic mean of a row or column of a matrix (matrices/nested vectors). So far I have been able to compute the arithmetic mean of the rows in a matrix, i.e.

```
(defn arithmean [x]
(let [data x num (count data)]
     (vec (apply map (fn [& items]
          (/ (apply + items) num)) data))))
```

I am more concerned with being able to input multiple nested vectors, something along the lines of [x & args] into the previous function. But would also be interested in being able to compute the mean of individual columns within a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer the solution into small, clear functions.

- a function that returns the `mean` of a single collection and
- functions that present the collections to be meaned, if there are several of them.

The function ...

```
(defn mean [cs] (/ (apply + cs) (count cs)))
```

... returns the mean of a collection.

To get the `mean`s of a collection of collections, define ...

```
(defn means [css] (vec (map mean css)))
```

... though this is maybe too small to be worth naming.

A matrix is (in your terms) a vector of column vectors, so the column means are just the `means`.

The row means are

```
(fn [matrix] (means (transpose matrix)))
```

where the transpose of a matrix is given by

```
(defn transpose [matrix] (apply map vector matrix))
```

It doesn't much matter whether you define these functions globally (using `defn`) or locally (using `fn`) or just quote the body in place.

You can adapt the layers of solution independently. For example, if need be, the following is a faster though less clear way to calculate a mean:

```
(defn mean [cs]
  (loop [remains cs, total 0, n 0]
    (if (empty? remains)
      (/ total n)
      (recur (next remains) (+ total (first remains)) (inc n)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a lot of options, if you are only doing it col at a time you can do:

```
(defn mean [vals]
  (apply /
        (reduce (fn [[tally count] val]
                  [(+ tally val)
                   (+ count 1)])
                [0 0]
                vals)))

(defn col-mean [vec-of-vec col]
  (mean
    (map (fn [v]
           (nth v col))
         vec-of-vec)))
```

you could also combine the two function to compute the mean of each column at once, basically keep `[tally count]` pairs for each col as you go through each row.  -- I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

you may want to look at this library and related ones (I don't know it, but it doesn't look bad)

https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix